# Random variates from fMultivar doesn't match density function

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I am trying to use the fMultivar package to plot histogram of t distribution and show that the corresponding density function matches the histogram.

The problem is that the histogram doesn't seem to match the density function.

Below is a minimal example.

```
library(fMultivar)

n = 50000
qtile = seq(-5,5,by=0.05)

xtt = rmvst(n,dim=1,df=3)
hist(xtt,300,xlim=c(-5,5),probability=TRUE)
lines(qtile,dmvst(qtile,dim=1,df=3),col='red')

xn = rmvsnorm(n,dim=1)
hist(xn,300,xlim=c(-5,5),probability=TRUE)
lines(qtile,dmvsnorm(qtile,dim=1),col='red')

xt = rt(n,df=3)
hist(xt,300,xlim=c(-5,5),probability=TRUE)
lines(qtile,dt(qtile,df=3),col='red')
```

As it is clear, xtt doesn't match the density function.
xn and xt does.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I am unconvinced,  at least regarding whether the random draws are giving a different distribution. The histograms look the same and I have looked at a `qqplot` of 'xt' and 'xtt' on a couple of runs and they seem to line up satisfactorily. Comparing the density lines to the histograms does suggest that the density estimates might be off and when I conduct this examination I agree that there is a systematic discrepancy between the density estimates:

```
plot( density(dt(qtile,df=3)- dmvst(qtile,dim=1,df=3) )  )
```

The distribution is bimodal and the dmvst densities are systematically greater than the dt densities in the tails. I do not see why the t-distribution should necessarily match the Skew-t distribution, however. Shouldn't you be comparing this to dst {in package: sn}? (This is the sort of question best posed to the package authors.)

Comment: It looks like a bug in `dmvst`: in dimension 1, 
the `df` argument is ignored and a gaussian distribution is used instead...

Comment: Vincent, it didn't occur to me to look at the code. Thank you for suggesting it. I suppose I should. Dwin, I did contact one of the authors because no maintainer was listed. Hopefully I'll hear back from him.